# Hired in a number-crunching function but want to try Sales

Tags: job-change

I've been hired in a number-crunching support role for less than 1 year but really want to be customer front facing as the type of work that I thought I would be doing, is not required.
I am interested in staying with my current company and they are a ton of sales roles being hired for and really the focus for us as a company.

How do I have the chat with my manager without making it look like any of the below:
1. I don't want to spend time in what I was hired to do and prove myself.
2. I am trying to shy away from responsibility and am not a team player.
I also want to have a dialogue that lets me try sales go back to my original job if I am not good at it, as I have never tried it before.

Comment: Your question is contradictory: either you are doing the work you were hired for or you are not. If you are not, it would be normal to address that with your manager. Can you clarify what "*the type of work that I thought I would be doing, is not required*" means?

Comment: You're also going to want to ask if HR has a lock box in which you can store your soul while you're over in sales.  You won't need while you're working in sales.

Answer (score 2):

Talk to your manager and ask them this. People rarely get fired for wanting to have a different career trajectory - especially if you're doing fine work in your current position!

1. It sounds like whatever you're doing is more technical and less social skills than sales, such that you don't need to "prove yourself" to get into sales. What I mean is, if you wanted to be head of whatever you're doing, then you'd need to prove yourself. But because the skills appear orthogonal, success in one doesn't mean success in another - so proving yourself in one is meaningless.
2. That just seems like something that wouldn't come out at all. You can just say "I'm really interested in this, can we start having fortnightly meetings about how I can move across". That way there is a time-box on how often you want to talk about this, it shows you've planned ahead, and you're consistently in your manager's mind about what you want to do.

Your last, unnumbered point is not something to bring up.  Sounds like loser-talk, and you cannot have that attitude in sales. Or anything, really. If you *are* terrible at sales, I'm sure your company will probably prefer to move you back, but don't ask about it - it just makes you sound less keen about sales.

Also, what books are you reading (or, sigh, online courses - I prefer books myself) about sales? Read some. Go right now to the library/bookstore and find the thinnest, smallest books and read them, that way you get a neat overview of sales and what to think about, so you have a better understanding what it entails and will also sound like you did a little research.

Answer (score 0):

I think bharal has it covered to be honest, though I can't comment so... you might want to see if it's possible to ask for a secondment into sales. It's common for larger firms to allow / offer people the chance to have a go working in another department for a few months. This could be a good angle to go into the conversation with your manager (and yes, do speak with your manager - there should be nothing wrong with expressing a desire to try something new).