# Want to move to Sales

Tags: career-development, new-job, job-change

I am in a number crunching role.
I have invested time after hours to gain knowledge about the business.
I want to move to Sales. 
What should be my next step be?
Should I be having a discussion with my boss and express interest or should I approach the Sales hiring manager directly?

Comment: Does your company advertise sales job vacancies internally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hired in a number-crunching function but want to try Sales](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/89132/hired-in-a-number-crunching-function-but-want-to-try-sales)

Answer (score 3):

Approach the sales hiring manager first and discuss your suitability for any role that might be there.  Also discuss anything more you need to do in order to be more suitable.

If you approach your own manager, you're communicating your wish to leave your team, which may negatively affect your time there, especially if you're not suitable for a sales role yet.